# Chat on Android

Tags: feature-request, chat, android-app

I'm someone who's active on Stack Overflow chatrooms when I have access to a personal computer. However, I don't have access to one on working days due to parental restrictions. So, to overcome this issue, I use the web based chat to chat whenever I need to. But that is too annoying!

I don't get notifications of new messages, neither do I get of mentions (mentions do come on the app, but... not on the web...). And it isn't only me who would be asking this feature; I'm pretty sure that a vast majority of the Android app users would agree with me.